# LXD - How can connect to the LXD API via unix socket domain under nodejs?

Tags: node.js, api, unix-socket, linux-containers, lxd

How can i connect to the LXD API via unix socket domain under nodejs?
I try the following code but fails. I've got this answer: **HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**

```
var net = require('net');

var lxdUSD='/var/lib/lxd/unix.socket';



var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect({path: lxdUSD},
            function() { //'connect' listener
                console.log('connected to socket!: '+lxdUSD);

});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.toString());
    client.end();
});

client.on('end', function() {
    console.log('disconnected from socket!: '+lxdUSD);
});

client.on('error', function() {
    console.log('Error');
    process.exit(-1);
});
setInterval(function(){
            var msg="GET /1.0/containers HTTP/1.1\r\n";
            console.log("write to socket: "+msg);
            client.write(msg);
            console.log("........");

}, 15*1000);
```

Trying the following from the command line it works:

```
echo -e "GET /1.0/containers HTTP/1.1\r\n" | socat unix-connect:/var/lib/lxd/unix.socket STDIO
```

The output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 15 Oct 2015 15:02:59 GMT
Content-Length: 135

{"type":"sync","status":"Success","status_code":200,"metadata":["/1.0/containers/pc01","/1.0/containers/pc02","/1.0/containers/pc03"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

Instead of

```
var msg="GET /1.0/containers HTTP/1.1\r\n";
```

Must be:

```
var msg="GET /1.0/containers HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
```